# jQuery not serialize correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to ajax submit 2 form (for `User` and `Client`). The 2 forms are almost identical but `User` is serialized as expected, the other one isn't. The 2 forms `return` js function as `onsubmit="return editUser();"` and `onsubmit="return editClient();"` respectively. I try to alert out the serialize data and they show for User:

```
id=7&username=somethingelse&password=123&is_admin=0&client=1
```

and for Client:

```
id=2&name=&logo=&phone=&email=&active=1&street=&city=&state=43&zip_code=
```

with all fields are filled (the 3 values are prefilled with PHP code).

Here is my js code to do the ajax:

```
function editUser() {
  console.log($('#editUserForm').serialize());
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'editUser.php',
    data: $('#editUserForm').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  }).always(function(){
    renderUsers();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  });
  return false;
}

function editClient() {
  console.log($('#editClientForm').serialize());
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'editClient.php',
    data: $('#editClientForm').serialize(),
    cache: false,
    dataType:'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
  }).always(function(){
    renderUsers();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  });;
  return false;
}
```

Comment with your question, I know I'm bad as explaining stuffs. Thanks for helping.

So to sum up the question: Why User and Client function is almost identical (different in ID and some fields in the form) but User works perfectly and Client doesn't?

For More info please [use this](http://leadclickz-phuduc1193.c9users.io/) to see the result. Login info is : admin pass.
After logged in, click on Users tab in the left sidebar and try to update Client, you will see it not working properly but you still can edit User

Comment: If you're using `.addEventListener` style Events, then you need to pass the event Object into your function then `event.preventDefault()` to prevent submission.

Comment: @PHPglue `return false` effectively does that

Comment: Not with `.addEventListener` in some Browsers.

Comment: @PHPglue look at question op is using inline `onsubmit`

Comment: What is specific problem or question?

Comment: Why is `return` there before your Event Handling function, inline? You should not event use inline JavaScript.

Comment: Because there is some problem with serialize Client form, the ajax is not submit to the database since required fields are not filled. So question is Why User can serialize and Client can't or not working properly?

Comment: Does it have to do with that `.removeClass()`? Can't see your HTML.

Comment: create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: http://leadclickz-phuduc1193.c9users.io/ For More info please use this to see the result. username:admin, pass:pass

Comment: After login, click on Users tab on the right sidebar to see my problem there.

Comment: working fine to me...`id=1&name=SomeName&logo=SomeLogo&phone=SomePhone&email=SomeEmail&active=1&street=SomeStreet&city=SomeCity&state=43&zip_code=77002`

Comment: But when you edit a field, does it change in the console.log? mine doesn't